# Memory Leaks while Navigating between pages in windows store app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have created windows store application with more than 200 pages. The problem here is as I am moving from one page to other, each page is leaving a small memory footprint in spite of releasing all references. I have checked all the major tools and profilers and made sure that there are no references holding them. Due to this, the memory is increasing to 500-600 odd MB and the application is eventually crashing.

As an illustration, I have created a sample project with 2 pages i.e. Page1 and Page2. The Page1 is heavy with lot of controls (including 1 button which redirects to Page2) where as Page2 is a blank page. Now in the App.xaml.cs, if I set the first page as Page2, the application launches and I can see the Page2. Not in the TaskManager, I see the memory as 17 MB.

Now, I have changed the App.xaml.cs to make the start page as Page1. When I launched the app and when I see the TaskManager, I see the memory as 50.4 MB which is fine until now considering the controls and images on the page. Now when I click the button which leads me to Page2, I see the memory in the taskManager as 50.7 MB (an increase of 300 KB).

I want to completely get rid of Page1, but I am facing problems.

Please note that I have taken care of all the basic memory related stuff like

Released all references to all objects in Page1
Made sure that Page1 is not having any reference using Profilers and tools like PerfView (RefTree) etc
Cleared BackStack
Disabled Cache
I am not sure how to handle this and I have used all the possible alternatives that I can think of.

I have created a demo app and uploaded it at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByK3PdkYyb7ZbG13TmM3cmFPcjA/view?usp=sharing

Please help!

Comment: Did you figure this out?